# List.js example not working

Tags: javascript, html, list, list.js

I'm trying to replicate the example on the List.js page, to create a new list. I copy and pasted the code on the example, but I'm getting an error on the .js library file.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://listjs.com/assets/javascripts/list.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Existing list</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>

  <ul class="list"></ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ],
  item: '<li><h3 class="name"></h3><p class="born"></p></li>'
};

var values = [{
    name: 'Jonny Strömberg',
    born: 1986
  },
  {
    name: 'Jonas Arnklint',
    born: 1985
  },
  {
    name: 'Martina Elm',
    born: 1986
}];

var userList = new List('users', options, values);

userList.add({
  name: "Gustaf Lindqvist",
  born: 1983
});
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
list.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Object.values (list.min.js:2)
    at f (list.min.js:2)
    at new <anonymous> (list.min.js:2)
    at o.add (list.min.js:2)
    at script.js:21
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: here `list.min.js` and `list.js` are two different scripts or same, bcoz issue you are getting is with `list.js`, if both are same remove `list.js`. It's working fine.

Comment: @shivamGupta Oops, my bad. However, I removed list.js and I still get an error: `list.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Object.values (list.min.js:2)
    at f (list.min.js:2)
    at new <anonymous> (list.min.js:2)
    at o.add (list.min.js:2)
    at script.js:21`

Comment: `at script.js:21`  what is `script.js`? If `script.js` is not required  Can you comment it and try.

Comment: @shivamGupta It is needed, you can check list.js's example here: http://listjs.com/examples/new-list/

Comment: I don't see anywhere `script.js` in there example, only `list.min.js` that's it.

Comment: @shivamGupta It's just the name I gave my java script file. It's where the JS code is placed.

Comment: try adding your `script.js` script tag just before `</body>`  tag

Comment: @shivamGupta That solved it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ],
  item: '<li><h3 class="name"></h3><p class="born"></p></li>'
};

var values = [{
    name: 'Jonny Strömberg',
    born: 1986
  },
  {
    name: 'Jonas Arnklint',
    born: 1985
  },
  {
    name: 'Martina Elm',
    born: 1986
}];

var userList = new List('users', options, values);

userList.add({
  name: "Gustaf Lindqvist",
  born: 1983
});
```

```html
<script src="http://listjs.com/assets/javascripts/list.min.js"></script>
<div id="users">
      <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
      <button class="sort" data-sort="name">Sort by name</button>

      <ul class="list"></ul>

  </div>
```